# Are there any tools to check for 'untrustworthy' certificates?

Tags: windows, security, ssl

I just a got a shiny new Windows laptop and in light of events like Lenovo's Superfish catastrophe last year I am wondering if there are any tools that can verify the veracity of the certificates on my machine. I would like something that can check for bad certificates or certificates from authorities with bad reputations.

Also, it would be nice if it could go one step further and identify certificates that might be trusted but that I do not need. For instance, when I received my laptop I immediately removed McAfee antivirus but I still have two McAfee certificates hanging around in my certificate store. I am almost certain I do not need them anymore and that I should remove them.

Answer (score 1):

`sigcheck -tv`, then `sigcheck -tuv` (sigcheck is freeware portable utility by Mark Russinovich), then, maybe, run `RCC` (I don't know, can we trust in their developer or no, besides, the source code is closed). These tests can compare your root certificates to The trust list of Microsoft and (if you will use RCC) same lists by Mozilla.